# Random query string appears in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Looks very strange, when I open the **/**, the browser will display something like `/#/?_k=dlo2cz` in the address. The random query string value changes every time when I refresh the page or switch to other route.

[image]

The code were copied and pasted and on [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) branch `1.0.0-rc1`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';


const App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>App</h1>
        {/* change the <a>s to <Links>s */}
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/inbox">Inbox</Link></li>
        </ul>

        {/*
          next we replace `<Child>` with `this.props.children`
          the router will figure out the children for us
        */}
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
});

const Message = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <h3>Message</h3>
  }
});
const About = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <h3>About</h3>
  }
});

const Inbox = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Inbox</h2>
        {/* Render the child route component */}
        {this.props.children || "Welcome to your Inbox"}
      </div>
    )
  }
})


// Finally, we render a <Router> with some <Route>s.
// It does all the fancy routing stuff for us.
React.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="about" component={About} />
      <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox}>
        {/* Add the route, nested where we want the UI to nest */}
        <Route path="messages/:id" component={Message} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body);
```

Answer (score 8):

To avoid that you can set `queryKey` to `false` while creating `browserHistory`. Following example illustrates that

```
import { Router, Route, BrowserHistory } from 'react-router';

let bHistory = BrowserHistory({
  queryKey: false
});

  <Router history={bHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="about" component={About} />
      <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox}>
        {/* Add the route, nested where we want the UI to nest */}
        <Route path="messages/:id" component={Message} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
```

**For React-router  v2.0.0**

```
import { Router, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'
const appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)({ queryKey: false })
<Router history={appHistory}/>
```

**Update:**

With current React-router version you don't need to install **history** npm module separately. It will be automatically installed as dependency while installing react-router.

If you get warning like this:

```
Warning: Using { queryKey: false } no longer works. Instead, 
just don't use location state if you don't want a key in your URL query string.
```

or `queryKey : false` is not working.

Then It could be the case that you may be having incompatible version of **history** module with **react-router**. Just check if you have installed history module separately, if that is the case then uninstall it. Above warning will go away.

**Edit: To get the exact dependencies**

If you want to know which dependencies your "react-router" needs check the package.json on github or you can try following command.

```
$ npm info "react-router@2.8.1" dependencies

{ 
   history: '^2.1.2',
  'hoist-non-react-statics': '^1.2.0',
   invariant: '^2.2.1',
   warning: '^3.0.0',
  'loose-envify': '^1.2.0' 
}
```

Comment: When I try this, it tells me `Uncaught TypeError: browserHistory is not a function`. Any ideas?

Comment: @denislexic Which version of react-router you are using?

Comment: How to avoid this in **v2.4**? It throws an error - `Warning: Using { queryKey: false } no longer works. Instead, just don't use location state if you don't want a key in your URL query string`

Comment: I get a blank page with this.

Comment: @WitVault Which version of history is compatible with v2.8.1 of react-router?

Comment: @saishreb Updated answer please check.

Comment: Thanks @WitVault. The random query string disappeared on updating history per your answer. However, the `#` still remains in the URL - `http://localhost:8080/#/`. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: @saishreb I think you are using hash history. I will suggest you to use browserHistory. Check this link for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289683/what-is-the-difference-between-hashhistory-and-browserhistory-in-react-router

Comment: @WitVault I used `const appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)({ queryKey: false })`. What is the browserHistory equivalent of `createHashHistory` here?

Answer (score 5):

It's a reference to the location state, it's documented [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#what-is-that-_kckuvup-junk-in-the-url): 
If want to get rid of it, you need a different storage for your history such as the browsers History API, for example:

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';    
<Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
```