# HashHistory vs. BrowserHistory

Tags: reactjs, browser-history, webpack-dev-server

I am using Node with Webpack-Dev-Server and React-Router.

In my `app.js` file I have:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
    <IndexRoute component={FindFriends} />
    <Route path="/you" component={YouAndYourFriends} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Using `browserHistory` the browser returns an error: `Cannot GET /you`

When I change `browserHistory` to `hashHistory`, everything works fine.

Where is my mistake? Or what should you do using `browserHistory`?

Comment: I believe that the problem is that the node server needs help to support pushState. Webpack puts everything into one bundle, and node doesn't recognize that sub-pages should be served with the same file.

If you scrutinize the output, you should see a message telling you to install pushstate:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pushstate-server

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289683/what-is-the-difference-between-hashhistory-and-browserhistory-in-react-router

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eofpZPRUnP8&list=PL55RiY5tL51oyA8euSROLjMFZbXaV7skS&index=16

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem.
Solved it by adding the following to my `webpack.config.js`

```js
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"), // Not Related but important
}
```

You can also toggle this option via the command-line:
https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#the-historyapifallback-option

In my case, I got it working by putting it in the config file.

Good luck !