# React router changes url but not view

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am having trouble changing the view in react with routing. I only want to show a list of users, and clicking on each user should navigate to a details page. Here is the router:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Users from "./components/Users";
import { Router, Route } from "react-router";
import Details from "./components/Details";

ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Route path="/" component={Users} />
        <Route path="/details" component={Details} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

When I use the url /details my browser navigates to that url, but does not change the view. Any other route throws 404 so it seems to recognize the route but not update.

Comment: I am getting two errors: One stating that using proptypes from the main react package is deprecated. Two stating using React.createClass is deprecated. I thought this to be unrelated, as the code works without using routing.

Comment: Is your component mounting correctly?

Answer (score 112):

You need to specify the attribute `exact` for your indexRoute, otherwise for even `/details` route it will still match with `/` . Also try to import `Route` from `react-router-dom`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Users from "./components/Users";

import Details from "./components/Details";

ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Users} />
        <Route path="/details" component={Details} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

UPDATE:

Another thing that you need to do is to attach your component Users with `withRouter`. You need to make use of `withRouter` only when your component is not receiving the `Router props`,

This may happen in cases when your component is a **nested child of a component rendered by the Router** or **you haven't passed the Router props to it** or when the component is not linked to the Router at all and is rendered as a separate component from the Routes.

In Users.js add

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

.........
export default withRouter(Users)
```

**[DOCS](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route)**

Comment: proptypes warning can be removed by installing `npm install -S 'prop-types'` and replacing React.PropsTypes with PropTypes . Also update your package.json to make use of the latest packaged since other packages may still be using React.PropTypes and React.createClass

Comment: Also Do you try to reload the page when url changes to see if it loads

Comment: I did try reloading page, it does not change the view.  It loads into the Users view even if the url is /#/details

Comment: Can you try the updated answer with `Route` imported from 'react-router-dom` instead of `react-router`

Comment: If its not yet solved, bind your users component with `withRouter`, it has helped me solve the same issue before. Let me know. I have updated the code too.

Comment: I am having the same problem. My url changes but the view on the page only changes when i reload the page. @ShubhamKhatri can you help me with that?

Comment: We also need to confirm that the BrowserRouter is at the parent node in the index page.

Comment: It seems that import {withRouter} from 'react-router' this no longer works with new package. This answer becomes even more confusing.

Answer (score 33):

I had the same issue and discovered that it was because I had a nested router. Once I removed the nested router, and simply put my component-specific routes within a switch component--the issue was resolved without having to use withRouter or make any additional changes.

```
<Router> // <--Remove nested Router
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/workflows" component={ViewWorkflows} />
      <Route path="/workflows/new" component={NewWorkflow} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Yusufbek is describing a similar issue. I think it's a lot cleaner to store the component related routes at a view level versus storing all of them in one main router. In a production app, that's going to be way too many routes to easily read through and debug issues.

Comment: I'm using **create-react-app** and this worked for me. Granted I built my router setup following some youtube tutorial, so create-react-app might not be related.

Comment: @DustinEnglish was it dennis ivy youtube tutorial?

Comment: this did the trick for me too

Answer (score 32):

You just have to wrap the components inside **withRouter**.

```
<Route exact path="/mypath" component={withRouter(MyComponent)} />
```

Here is a sample App.js file:

```
...
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Profile from "./pages/Profile";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={withRouter(Home)} />
          <Route exact path="/profile" component={withRouter(Profile)} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Additional**

If you are using react router, **componentWillReceiveProps** will get called whenever the url changes.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    var currentProductId = nextProps.match.params.productId;
    var nextProductId = nextProps.match.params.productId; // from the new url
    ...
}
```

**Note**

Alternatively, you may also wrap the component in **withRouter** before exporting, but then you have to ensure a few other things. I usually skip this step.

```
export default withRouter(Profile)
```

Comment: < Route exact path="/mypath" component={withRouter(MyComponent)} />

worked for me

Answer (score 31):

React Router v5 doesn't work with React 18 StrictMode
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7870

Comment: Oh, this is IT! Big thanks! Somebody mentions in the link you provided, that a temp solution can be moving `React Strict mode` inside `BrowserRouter`, because apparently   "It is not working if BrowserRouter is a child of StrictMode"

Comment: Awesome! This worked for me after burning hours trying everything.

Answer (score 23):

I have faced the same problem but I fixed it. I have placed the home page as the last. It works for me. Just like below.

```js
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
    import Users from "./components/Users";
    import { Router, Route } from "react-router";
    import Details from "./components/Details";

    ReactDOM.render((
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Route path="/details" component={Details} />
            <Route path="/" component={Users} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    ), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: Using the `exact` property would've also resolved this for you.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar issue but with different structure. I've added one Router that will handle all routes, I've used Switch component to switch views. But actually, it didn't. Only URL changed but not view. The reason for this was the Link component used inside of SideBar component which was outside of the Router component. (Yes, I've exported SideBar with "withRouter", not worked). 
So, the solution was to move my SideBar component which holds, all Link components into my Router.

**The problem is in my linkers, they are outside of my router**

```
<div className="_wrapper">
  <SideBar /> // Holds my all linkers
  <Router>
     <Switch>
       <Route path="/" component={Home} />
       <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
     </Switch>
  </Router>
 </div>
```

**Solution was moving my linkers into my router**

```
<div className="_wrapper">
  <Router>
     <SideBar /> // Holds my all linkers
     <Switch>
       <Route path="/" component={Home} />
       <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
     </Switch>
  </Router>
</div>
```

Comment: helping yourself made my day. I was trying it with two separated Routers. One was within the navbar and one within the body to accomodate the component. Now I put everything within the same Router in the parent component and things work as they should.

Comment: Excellent - my exact issue. Thank you

Comment: Thanks! You saved me!!

Comment: I have tried everything, including withRouter, but only this solution did worked ... a bit of explanation would be helpfull to understand why this is happening

Comment: @Jim I think react-router uses context API, and `<Router />` aka `<BrowserRouter />`  provides a context to the route matchers like `<Route />`, `<Switch />`  and navigation components like `<Link />`, `<Redirect />`. In order to provide the same context, you have to wrap all children components within the context provider which is `<Router />`.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue with `react-router-dom 5`

The problem was caused by the `history` package.
The version I was using was `5.0.0` but they don't work together.

Fixed by downgrading `history` to `4.10.1`

Related issue: https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/804

Answer (score 12):

According to this issue [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7870), react-router-dom isn't compatible with React 18 because BrowserRouter is a child of StrictMode.

So to resolve the issue.

Instead of this:

```
<React.StrictMode><BrowserRouter>...</BrowserRouter></React.StrictMode>
```

Do this:

```
<BrowserRouter><React.StrictMode>...</React.StrictMode></BrowserRouter>
```

It worked for me this way, I hope it helps.

Comment: This worked for me in `v5.3.1`. Also `v5.3.2` fixed this issiue.

Comment: After hours of debugging, this fixed my issue (which was due to v5.3.0).

Answer (score 9):

BrowserRouter fails to maintain history in your case. Use "Router" instead, Usage of this with custom history as props may help resolve your problem.

```
import {Router, Route, Switch, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Profile from "./pages/Profile";
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';

export const customHistory = createBrowserHistory();  //This maintains custom history

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={customHistory}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Then in your components, import customHistory from 'App' and use that to navigate.

```
customHistory.push('/pathname');
```

Hope This help! :)

Comment: no need to the `exact` attribute when you use `Switch`

Answer (score 8):

When using Redux and   I had similar issues where the url was updating in the address bar but the app was not loading the respective component.  I was able to solve by adding withRouter to the export:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponentName))
```

Comment: But, it will work for functional component?

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I'd mistakenly nested two `BrowserRouter`s.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add exact to the index route and rather than enclosing those **Route** components by div, use **Switch** from react-router-dom to switch between the routes.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Users from "./components/Users";

import Details from "./components/Details";

ReactDOM.render((
  <div>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Users} exact/>
        <Route path="/details" component={Details} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 5):

I Tried adding "exact" in front of the home path
like this

> `<Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>`

It is working fine...

Comment: Like, realy moving `exact` in front of `to` instead being it after helped. Want my hour of debugging back

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue with React Router version 4:

By clicking `<Link />` component, URL would change but views wouldn't.

One of views was using `PureComponent` rather than `Component` (imported from `react`) and that was the cause.

By replacing all route rendered components that were using `PureComponent` to `Component`, my issue was resolved.

(Resolution source: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4975#issuecomment-355393785)

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it for me. But it was just the component that contained Switch that I had to extend from Component instead of PureComponent in order for live view changing to work.

Comment: I've changed my pure component to component, it's not working for me though.

Answer (score 4):

None of the answers here solved my issue, turns out I had to add a dependency to my `useEffect` hook. I had something like this:

`App.js`

```
<Route
  path="/product/:id"
  component={MyComponent}
/>
```

`MyComponent.jsx`

```
const { id } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

I had a button to change to another product, which would only update the `:id` on the url, I could see the url changed, but no effect on the page. This change fixed the issue:

`MyComponent.jsx`

```
const { id } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, [id]); // add 'id' to dependency array
```

Now when the `id` changes, it trigger a function to update the data and works as expected.

Comment: Dude, you are a life saver. I was trying to figure out what's going on for over 2 hours and your solution worked like a charm. I was doing the exact mistake. Thank you !

Comment: In my case, I was returning a cleanup function in `useEffect` function which was unmounting the whole component. But, during the refresh, it loaded, because, the id remained the same and `useEffect` function was no more called.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm there no any SWITCH to actually switch views.

this is how i use router to switch from landin page to main site

```
//index.jsx    
ReactDOM.render( (<BrowserRouter><App/></BrowserRouter>), document.getElementById('root') );


//App.jsx
render()
{
    return <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Lander}/>
            <Route path='/vadatajs' component={Vadatajs}/>
        </Switch>
    </div>
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Martins_Abilevs/4jko7arp/11/

ups i found you use different router ..sorry  then maybe this fiddle be for you useful

https://fiddle.jshell.net/terda12/mana88Lm/

maybe key of solution is hiden in line for main render function ..

```
Router.run(routes, function(Handler) {
    React.render(<Handler />, document.getElementById('container'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar issue I resolve to like this please have a look I hope it's working.

You need to use **componentWillReceiveProps** function in your component.

clicked a link first time by calling url www.example.com/content1/  componentDidMount() is run.

Now when you click another link say www.example.com/content2/ same component is called but this time prop changes and you can access this new prop under componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) which you can use to call API Or make state blank and get new data.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
     //call your API and update state with new props
}
```

Comment: This function `componentWillReceiveProps` is now [deprecated](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops)

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had:

```
export MyClass extends React.Component
```

with:

```
export default withRouter(MyClass)
```

Meanwhile, in my App.js, I had:

```
import { MyClass } from './MyClass'
```

Those playing the home game can see my problem.  I was not getting the import with the Router passed into the child classes.  To clean this up, I moved the *withRouter* call into the Route component declaration:

```
<Router exact path={'/myclass'} component={withRouter(MyClass)} />
```

Back in MyClass, I changed it to a default export:

```
export default MyClass extends React.Component
```

And then finally, in App.js, I changed my import to:

```
import MyClass from './MyClass'
```

Hopefully this helps someone.  This ensures I didn't have two ways to export the same class, thus bypassing the *withRouter* prepend.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem. Although it is not a very effective solution, I solved it with a cunning method.
The ComponentDidMount method works every time our url changes.
Within the method we can compare the previous url with the current url and we can the state change  or page refresh.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.match.url !== prevProps.match.url) {
        //this.props.history.go(0) refresh Page
        //this.setState(...) or change state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Users} />
<Route exact path="/details" component={Details} />
```

I was also facing the same issue which was resolved using the `exact` attribute. try to use the `exact` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I met trouble too.

`https://github.com/chengjianhua/templated-operating-system`

And I have tried the solutions metioned by Shubham Khatri, but It doesn't work.

---

I solved this problem, maybe can help you.

`https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md`

According the above guide document, when you use `PureComponent` or use with state management tools like `redux`, `mobx` ... It may block the update of your route. Check your route component, ensure you did't block the rerender od your component.

Answer (score 1):

You should check this out: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md

Therefore it's definitely not `Users` or `Details`, because they are directly rendered by `<Route>`, and the `location` will get passed to `props`.

I am wondering, why do you need the `<div>` between `<BrowserRouter>` and `<Route>`? Remove that and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a conditional Layout:

```
class LayoutSwitcher extends Component {
  render () {
    const isLoggedIn = this.props.isLoggedIn
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        { isLoggedIn
          ? <MainLayout {...this.props} />
          : <Login />
        }
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

and rewrote the conditions like so:

```
  render () {
    const isLoggedIn = this.props.isLoggedIn
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return <MainLayout {...this.props} />
    }
    return <Login />
  }
```

This solved it. In my case, it seems that the context was lost.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same Issue.
I don't think that in this case he needs to add the prop withRouter,
just check in your NavLink you write the good path name as details.
for the route try to start from the specific route to the general one like

```
<Route path="/details" component={Details} />
<Route path="/" component={Users} />
```

in your NavLink it should be something like this

```
 <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/details">
   details<span className="sr-only">(current)</span>
 </NavLink>
```

a remarque for the import its better to start by importing all stuff related to React after that import the other module
like this one:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Users from "./components/Users";
import { Router, Route } from "react-router";
import Details from "./components/Details";
```

come like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Router, Route } from "react-router";

import Users from "./components/Users";    
import Details from "./components/Details";
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, switching to HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter solved my issue

Comment: Switching to hashrouter just for this usecase is not a good approch, it wont have access to state, history or anything... you'll miss a lot rich functionalities, and all of your urls will end with with # symbols

Answer (score 1):

I was accidentally using a BrowserRouter around my Link's.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Link to="/" component={Users} />
        <Link to="/details" component={Details} />
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just started having this issue recently, take a look at https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7415

The issue is with react-router-dom 5+ and the history dependency.

If you installed it separately using `yarn install history` you need to uninstall it, do `yarn install history@4.10.1`

Answer (score 1):

In my case it wasn't working because I imported Browser Router as Router, Like This:

```
<Router>

     <div> <Navbar/></div>

      <Routes>
         <Route exact path="/" element={<Pageone/>}></Route>
         <Route  path="/home" element={<Home/>}></Route>
         <Route  path="/about" element={<About/>}></Route>
         <Route  path="/contact" element={<Contact/>}></Route>  
      </Routes>

    
    <div><Footer /></div>


    </Router>
    </div>
```

Then It was fixed by adding BrowserRouter instead:

```
 <BrowserRouter>

     <div> <Navbar/></div>

      <Routes>
         <Route exact path="/" element={<Pageone/>}></Route>
         <Route  path="/home" element={<Home/>}></Route>
         <Route  path="/about" element={<About/>}></Route>
         <Route  path="/contact" element={<Contact/>}></Route>  
      </Routes>

    
    <div><Footer /></div>


    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import React from "react";

import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Users from "./components/Users";
import { Router, Route } from "react-router";


import Details from "./components/Details";

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Wrapper} >
            <IndexRoute component={Users} />
            <Route path="/details" component={Details} />
        </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: Define a Wrapper component which will render this.props.children.
This will route properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it importing the history from the @types folder in node_modules. I imported it from npm (npm i @history)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you check the User and Details components. They should not have a Router component in them. If you are using a `<Link to=../>` inside them which is inside a `<Router>` try removing the Router and only use the Link.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using the `history` package for navigation and if you are using the `react-router v5`, then you may have to downgrade the `history` package to `4.10.1` until the `history` package developers issue a new release with the fix. As of writing this, the latest release version of `history` package is `v5.0.1`, and if you see a new release than this, you can try with that version first to see if it works, before doing the downgrade to `4.10.1`

Issue Link -> https://github.com/remix-run/history/issues/804

Answer (score 0):

If you configure the router component like the above example and try to access history.push or props.history.push from any component, you may face the issue of not rendering the component while changing the URL. You can fix this by importing Router directly from react-router-dom instead of importing BrowserRouter as Router. You can find the corrected code below.

for e.g: import {
Router,
Switch,
Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

not:
import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
Switch,
Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this old questsion.

OP's `<Switch>` block is missing there on the quoted code.  That should definitely stop things from working properly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30569933)

Answer (score 0):

I just had a problem like this in `react router v6` and it turns out that I was using nested routing without the `<Outlet/>` component so whenever I clicked a nested child route the URL changed but nothing happened?

this is all because I didn't tell it where to render the child component inside the parent and this is obviously done using the `<Outlet/>` component.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a useEffect. Solution of react-router V6

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const history = useNavigate();

useEffect(() => {
if (logged) history('/', { replace: true });
}, [logged, history]);
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer specifically for those having upgraded to `react-router-dom` version 6:

**Uninstall the dependencies `@types/react-router` and `@types/react-router-dom`** from your app's package.json. These packages do not go past version 5, because v6 provides its own type definitions. Keeping the old definitions around causes this problem.

This does of course assume your routing is otherwise correct. A simple, correct v6 routing setup might look like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

<BrowserRouter>
    {/* other components, optionally */}

        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}></Route>
            <Route path="/users" element={<Users />}></Route>  
        </Routes>

    {/* other components, optionally */}
</BrowserRouter>
```

**Bonus note:** according to the official [upgrade guide](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#upgrade-to-react-router-v6), you can also remove the `history` dependency as this is now a direct dependency of react-router-dom. If you happen to directly reference types from the `history` module in your app though, such as `Location` or `LocationDescriptorObject`, use `npm install --save-dev @types/history@4.7.11` to still have access to these types. Do not use [the 5.0.0 version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/history), as it is only a stub package with no content.