# react router not rendering the view but url is changing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom, react-router-component

I have two tabs: **Profile** and **Friends** and the **navlink** are as follows

```
<Navlink to={'/dashboard/profile/'  + (tab.url) + '/' + userId}>{tab.name}</Navlink>
```

where tab = [{
        "name": "Profile",
        "url": 'timeline'
    },
    {
        "name": "Friends",
        "url": 'friends'
    }]

Inside my render() I have route defined as

```
<Route path="/dashboard/profile/:screenId/:userId" component={this.Routing}/>
```

where **screenId** is Timeline/Friends depending on which tab is clicked

and the Routing function is

```
Routing =({ match })=>{
    userId = match.params.userId;
    switch(match.params.screenId){
        case "timeline": return <Timeline/>;
        case "friends": return <Friends/>
        default : return <NoMatch/>;
    }
}
```

So the problem is whenever any tab is being selected, the url changes but the Routing function is not triggered so as a result the route is not working. Basically anything after **/dashboard/profile/** doesn't work.

I also tried this inside my render():

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/dashboard/profile/timeline/userId" component={Timeline}/>
  <Route path="/dashboard/profile/friends/userId" component={ContactUs}/>
</Switch>
```

But then also it is not working and the problem remains. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You would write your Route like `<Switch>
  <Route path="/dashboard/profile/timeline/:userId" component={Timeline}/>
  <Route path="/dashboard/profile/friends/:userId" component={ContactUs}/>
</Switch>`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Tried that as well but didn't work

Comment: In the component where you have specified Navlink, do you pass the Route props

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri For that I used render, <Route path="/dashboard/profile/timeline/userId" render={()=><Timeline/>}/>

Comment: which exactly is the issue, you need to write `<Route path="/dashboard/profile/timeline/userId" render={(props)=><Timeline {...props}/>}/>` Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351752/react-router-changes-url-but-not-view/43352623#43352623

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Tried all the solutions, but I am afraid it doesn't work

Comment: Can you please make a reproducible demo of your problem on codesandbox or jsfiddle