# sibling routes not working in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, nested-routes

I have a component called **Profile** and it has two children components 
**Timeline** and **Friends**.

I can route to the timeline component inside profile from any other component like this:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/dashboard/profile/timeline/'+userId}}></Link>
```

But once I am in this url, after that if I want to route to friends section, which is a sibling to timeline I try routing using this in Profile component

```
<Route path="/dashboard/profile/:screenId/:userId" component={this.Routing}/>
```

where Routing function is

```
Routing =({ match })=>{
    switch(match.params.screenId){
        case "timeline": return <Timeline/>;
        case "friends": return <Friends/>
        default : return <NoMatch/>;
    }
}
```

But the problem is it is not working, the Routing function is not being triggered when I click on the navlink

```
<NavLink to={'/dashboard/profile/'  + (tab.url) + '/' + userId} activeClassName="selectedTab">
   <div>{tab.name}</div>
</NavLink>
```

This navlink is in the Profile component. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does the url change to the updated Route

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Yes it does change

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass on the Router props to the component in order for Routing to take place

```
Routing =({ match, ...rest })=>{
    switch(match.params.screenId){
        case "timeline": return <Timeline match={match} {...rest}/>;
        case "friends": return <Friends match={match} {...rest}/>
        default : return <NoMatch match={match} {...rest}/>;
    }
}
```

Comment: @SubhamKhatri Tried that as well, but it didn't work

Comment: Where exactly is the Navlink component

Comment: @SubhamKhatri It is not a component, it is inside a div which is in the Profile component

Comment: In that case Profile component needs to receive the Router props, you can either make sure you pass them to it or use withRouter, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351752/react-router-changes-url-but-not-view/43352623#43352623