# React router: Link changes url but doesn't load component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

this has been driving me crazy. I have an app using react-router. When I load from the server everything works correctly. But when I try to hit a route through the Link component, it just changes the url and the component doesn't get loaded. Someone please help me how to solve this problem .

```
         class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Item: 5,
      skip: 0
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  urlParams() {
    return `http://localhost:3001/meetups?filter[limit]=${(this.state.Item)}&&filter[skip]=${this.state.skip}`
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({skip: this.state.skip + 1})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href={this.urlParams()}>Example link</a>
        <pre>{this.urlParams()}</pre>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change link</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.querySelector('div#my-example' ))
```

Comment: Are you can please show your imports?

Comment: Consider using the solution from here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351752/react-router-changes-url-but-not-view

Comment: because Link is outside of Router component. Router is not aware of that link, do it like this: `<Router><div><Link to="/dashboard/products">Products</Link><Switch>....all routes here</Switch></div></Router>`

Comment: @MayankShukla Tried with inside Router component but Not working

Comment: can you update your answer with the new code?

Comment: @MayankShukla It working T. Thanks

Comment: @MayankShukla. I am using nested Routing structure might look like `dashboard/products` .. I added exact to every route . could you please suggest any new method ?

Comment: follow this react-router details, very well explained, i hope it will answer all your questions. [link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when I use react-router,  link outside of route, there'll be warning it's forbidden. So at this time, I will use tag a or history.