# React router changes url but not page loading

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history, react-dom

```js
// this is my index.js
import React, {  } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store/configureStore";
import { Router } from "react-router";

import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import history from "./history";

// append app to dom
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router  history={history}>
        <App  />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
 
);
```

```js
//this is my app.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Inscription from "../src/pages/inscription";


class App extends Component {

  render() {
 
    return (  
     < BrowserRouter>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Inscription} />
      </ BrowserRouter>   
    );
  }
}
export default (App);
```

I am having changing the view in react with routing. It seems I have tried everything I can google with no luck. the page affiche but doesn't load
Please same one can help mee :(

Comment: Can you add the relevant routing code? As it stands, the issue you're getting already has a bunch of posts about it, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351752/react-router-changes-url-but-not-view

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately that isn't enough info. Post all your relevant code so we can debug and help.

Comment: Could you please add the code into your question and not as an answer? You can edit the question as well. Thanks!

Comment: I re post the publication can  same one help me please

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `BrowserRouter` from the App component. You have already provided a `Router` in **index.js**. Also in case you want to define multiple routes, you have to use `switch`

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Inscription} />
    <Route exact path="/hello" component={HelloComponent} />
<Switch>
```