# react-router-dom Link doesn't push user to new link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a Route with the path "/contacts/:userIds"

```
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/contacts/:usersIds"
                  component={contacts}
                />
```

I' having a problem where if a user is on the page */contacts/123* and then clicks on a different Link component like *contacts/234* then the browser link changes but the page stays the same as the user would still be on the page */contacts/123* instead of being on */contacts/234*.

Here's the code simplified, it's a map of ListItems with the Link component from "react-router-dom":

```
                     <ListItem
                        key={key}
                        button
                        component={Link}
                        to={
                          `/contacts/` +
                          (user1_user2)
                        }
                      >
```

Comment: Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351752/react-router-changes-url-but-not-view

Answer (score 0):

You can add a useEffect in your function with `props.location.pathname` dependency which will execute whenever there is change in URL.

```
  useEffect( () => {
   console.log(newUrl, props.location.pathname)
}, [props.location.pathname] )
```