# Reactjs redirect route not working but url updates

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I required to redirect from parent path to child path as a default. but the route is getting updates. but the component is not rendering.

here is my route details:

Lazy part:

```
const UK = React.lazy(() => import("./components/page-projects/project-uk/project-uk.component"));
const FR = React.lazy(() => import("./components/page-projects/project-france/project-france.component"));
const LT = React.lazy(() => import("./components/page-projects/project-lithuania/project-lithuania.component"));
```

Route path:

```
 <Redirect from="/projects" to="/projects/united-kingdom">
    <Route path="/projects/united-kingdom" component={UK}></Route>
    <Route path="/projects/france" component={FR}></Route>
    <Route path="/projects/lithuania" component={LT}></Route>
 </Redirect>
```

what is wrong here? any one help me? my version of `react is 17x`

Comment: Did you import `{BrowserRouter}` or `{Router}` from react-router?

Comment: I did {BrowserRouter as Route}

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351752/react-router-changes-url-but-not-view#:~:text=This%20may%20happen%20in%20cases,separate%20component%20from%20the%20Routes.&text=You%20just%20have%20to%20wrap%20the%20components%20inside%20withRouter.) help you then?

Comment: actually which is preferred and why?

Comment: BrowserRouter is the preferred and correct way. Not sure about the exact reason but importing Router doesn't work as expected. I wanted to make sure you did the correct import first

Comment: Yes, I do correct import only. because if i with another answer that works for me. but wondering why my approach not works

Answer (score 0):

The other routes don't have to be children of `Redirect`.

You should be doing something like this

```
<Switch>
  <Redirect from="/projects" to="/projects/united-kingdom" />
  <Route path="/projects/united-kingdom" component={UK} />
  <Route path="/projects/france" component={FR} />
  <Route path="/projects/lithuania" component={LT} />
</Switch>
```

Reference https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect

Comment: Not required to nested under parent? then how to set common pros to share with children

Comment: I don't get, can you elaborate more which props or how you want to pass them? The route props will be available in all the routes

Answer (score 0):

The `<Switch />` component will only render the first route that matches the path. Once it finds the first route that matches the path, it will not look for any other matches. Not only that, it allows for nested routes to work properly and since the `Redirect` is a route you should wrap under the `Switch` component

```
<Switch>
  <Redirect from="/projects" to="/projects/united-kingdom" />
  <Route path="/projects/united-kingdom" component={UK} />
  <Route path="/projects/france" component={FR} />
  <Route path="/projects/lithuania" component={LT} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: will this render inside of my projects component? or I need to do any fine tune with my projects component?

Comment: yes it should be working fine and it should be wrapped under ```<BrowserRouter>```