# React-Router: Component is not rendered but URL changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I am new to React js.
I am implementing the drawer (material-ui), so when user clicks on left menu (LeftMenu.jsx); the respective component should get render in the center (i.e, MainContent.jsx)

Unfortunately, I am getting following error:
`Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`
But if I enclosed Link in LeftMenu.jsx then URL changes but view does not get render.

I tried the solutions given in [React router changes url but not view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351752/react-router-changes-url-but-not-view) but still the problem is not solved.

Following are the list of components:

Status.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class Status extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return <div>Status</div>;
  }
}
export default Status;
```

AdminPanelLayout.jsx

```
export default function AdminPanelLayout() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    if (open) {
      setOpen(false);
    } else {
      setOpen(true);
    }
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
          [classes.appBarShift]: open,
        })}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Admin Panel
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        variant="permanent"
        className={clsx(classes.drawer, {
          [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
          [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
        })}
        classes={{
          paper: clsx({
            [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
            [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
          }),
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.toolbar}></div>
        <Divider />
        <LeftMenu></LeftMenu>
      </Drawer>
      <MainContent></MainContent>
    </div>
  );
}
```

MainContent.jsx

```
export default function MainContent() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Router>
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/Status" component={withRouter(Status)}>
            <Status />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <span>testing</span>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

LeftMenu.jsx

```
export default function LeftMenu() {
  return (
    <div>
      <List>
        {["Status", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem button key={text} component={Link} to="/Status">
            <ListItemIcon>
              {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
      <Divider />
      <List>
        {["All mail", "Trash", "Spam"].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem button key={text}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  );
}
```

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import AdminPanelLayout from "./components/AdminPanelLayout";
import LeftMenu from "./components/LeftMenu";

function App() {
  return <AdminPanelLayout></AdminPanelLayout>;
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either use

```
<Route path="/Status" component={Status}>
```

or

```
<Route path="/Status">
 <Status />
</Route>
```

Also you should not be doing this `component={withRouter(Status)}` because this is equivalent to `component={Status}`. The purpose of `withRouter` is to get a component which is not rendered via `Route` to get access to the `route props` . Since `Status` is already rendered via `Route` wrapping it with `withRouter` is not needed.

[codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-resonance-id9tp?file=/src/Components/AdminPanel.js) - Hope this helps !

Comment: Have you wrapped your `AdminPanelLayout` with `Router` ? . How are you rendering AdminPanelLayout ?

Comment: Edit the post to include app.js code. Even after wrapping AdminPanelLayout with Router. Its not rendering.

Comment: Wrap your AdminPanelLayout with `Router` and Remove the `Router` from MainContent.jsx

Comment: Edited the answer to add a codeSandbox link . Let me know if it helps .