# missing dependency for React Hook useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hi this is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-tdd-e8s1ej?file=/src/App.js

for the react-router-dom, I used the ver5.2+.

I couldn't for the life of me figure out the missing dependency, I try searching for answers here but it told me to add me to the dependency to no avail.

I appreciate any enlighten on this issue, thank you

Comment: Where do you see the error, in which file?

Comment: Product.js is the file, UseEffect (data1)

Comment: in which row? line 13?

Comment: You can remove the Dependency Array. I think that is not needed in your case.

Answer (score 1):

because you're using something that is defined outside of `useEffect` (in this case `fetchProduct` function), react will throw a warning saying **if something changes inside the `fetchProduct` function, `useEffect` will not catch that change.** for example: let's say your `match.params.id` inside `fetchProduct` is equal to `1` when the page first loaded, but later on `match.params.id` becomes `2`, the `fetchProduct` function inside `useEffect` will still use `1` as `match.params.id` because `useEffect` didn't catch the changes.

so to solve the warning, there are 2 options. first is to write the `fetchProduct` function logic inside `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  axios
    .get(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/?id=${match.params.id}`)
    .then((res) => {
      setData(res.data);
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}, [match.params.id]);
```

having `match.params.id` in dependency array to make sure `useEffect` is up to date.

but if you need to reuse the `fetchProduct` function, then you should do something like:

```js
const fetchProduct = useCallback(() => {
  axios
    .get(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/?id=${match.params.id}`) // use match to get product id
    .then((res) => {
      setData(res.data);
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}, [match.params.id]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetchProduct();
}, [fetchProduct]);
```

Comment: Hi @Layhout, thanks for the efforts! I understand it a bit better now, I tried to change it, but upon clicking the link, I did not manage to get just a single product page (products/1 e.g.)

Comment: that is something to do with `react-router-dom`.

Comment: just [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71835644/17308201) out that it is a bug. turn off `StrictMode` will fix it.

Comment: in fact, you don't need to turn off `StrictMode`. move the `<StrictMode>` tag from `index.js` to `app.js` and put it between `<Router>` and `<div>`.

Comment: hi I have move it, I tried in vs code (I have also upgraded react-router-dom to v6) but I get >> No routes matched location "/products/4"

Comment: the syntax of `react-route-dom` [v5](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) and [v6](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial) are different. you need pick one and stick with it.

Comment: if you pick v6, you need to undo the move `<StrictMode>` tag and rewrite your `app.js`.

Comment: must I use match or useParams to find id? or both are fine? in v6

Comment: yes, i think that the only way.

Answer (score 0):

It is a warning, Kindly look through the documentation of `useEffect()`

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html.

Whenever you add in a dependency in the array, it will watch all those values and it will re-run the `useEffect` hook. whenever that particular value/dependency changes.

[https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#:~:text=React%20to%20skip%20applying%20an%20effect%20if%20certain%20values%20haven%E2%80%99t%20changed%20between%20re%2Drenders](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#:%7E:text=React%20to%20skip%20applying%20an%20effect%20if%20certain%20values%20haven%E2%80%99t%20changed%20between%20re%2Drenders)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `fetchProduct` function in your effect, so it is a dependency. The error message should tell you that.

One way to fix it is to move the `fetchProduct` function inside the effect. Then `match` will become a dependency of the effect, but you probably want that as if `match` changes you most likely want to fetch the new product.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // function fetchProducts
  const fetchProduct = () => {
    axios
      .get(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/?id=${match.params.id}`) // use match to get product id
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
  fetchProduct();
}, [match]);
```