Url is changing but page is only appearing after reloading
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Onboarding from './components/Onboarding/Onboarding';
import Login from './components/Login/Login';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="flex justify-center w-[386px] h-[800px] mb-6 mt-5 ml-[35%] box-sizing:border-box rounded-sm overflow-auto -z-50">
        <Switch>
          <Route  exact path="/"  component={Onboarding} />
          
          <Route path="/login"  component={Login} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;


when i am cliking on a button which will redirect me to the login page , So after clicking it URL is changing but page is not appearing until i reload the page.
 const handleRedirectToLogin = () => {
    history.push('/login'); // Navigate to /login route using navigate
  };
<button className="progress-button absolute bottom-4 right-4" onClick={handleRedirectToLogin}>
       <span className="icon">→</span>
 </button


Which version of react-router are you using?

If you are using the history package for navigation and are encountering issues with React Router v5, it might be due to compatibility problems with the history package version. Specifically, if the URL changes but the Login component only appears after reloading, it might be related to a known issue with the history package version 5.x.
Solution
You should downgrade the history package to version 4.10.1 to resolve this issue

Issue Link -> https://github.com/remix-run/history/issues/804
Related Answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/69561848/9557500

