# React router doesn't work after deploying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, react-router-v4

I deployed a react-app on Google Cloud Platform:
https://just-palace-214904.appspot.com/

However only the first page shows up and the hyperlinks don't work. They worked fine when I was running the app on localhost. Below is my setup:

index.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import SignIn from './components/SignIn';
import SignUp from './components/SignUp';
import ForgotPass from './components/ForgotPass';

ReactDOM.render((<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact={true} path="/" component={SignIn}/>
    <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp}/>
    <Route path="/forgot" component={ForgotPass}/>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>), document.getElementById('root'));
```

My hyperlinks:

```js
<a href="/forgot">Forgot password?</a><br/>
<a href="/signup">Create account</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `Link` instead of anchor tags.

Change

```
 <a href="/forgot">Forgot password?</a><br/>
 <a href="/signup">Create account</a>
```

to

```
<Link to="/forgot">Forgot Password?</Link><br/>
<Link to="/signup">Create account</Link>
```

The `Link` is from `react-router-dom` package.

Here is the working example.
https://codesandbox.io/s/qz4l7nzv09

Comment: Thank you! I was about to pull my hair out!

Comment: Happy to help! It is actually a known issue with react-router. For more information you can visit https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/394

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why, the similar issue I have faced earlier and using `HashRouter` worked fine rather than using `BrowserRouter`:

```
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
```

---

Ah, I found a blog explaining differences between them [here](https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf).

> The `BrowserRouter` should be used when you have a server that will handle dynamic requests (knows how to respond to any possible URI), while the `HashRouter` should be used for static websites (where the server can only respond to requests for files that it knows about).

Comment: That's what I was using but it kept giving me warnings while I was debugging and a lot of people said HashRouter is old and shouldn't be used.

Comment: @MuhammadAli is your website static? Then, you must use HashRouter, otherwise it will not work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289683/what-is-the-difference-between-hashhistory-and-browserhistory-in-react-router